# How to retrieve azure oms workspace id and key?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-oms

Is there a way to retrieve the oms workspace ID and Key in Azure via the az cli or azure powershell?
I am deploying k8s clusters (in Azure) and automatically want to deploy the oms container agent via helm. I need a workspace ID and key for that and I don't want to create the workspace by hand and manually put the Id and Key in my release job :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure Power Shell to do this, for example:

```
$rgname = "shuioms"
$omsname = "shuioms"
##get workspaceid
$oms=Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName shuioms -Name shuioms
$workspaceID = $oms.CustomerId
#get oms key
$key=Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKeys -ResourceGroupName shuioms -Name shuioms
```

Comment: Currently, Azure CLi does not support oms, so I suggest you could use Power Shell to get workspace ID and key.

Comment: Thank you so much! In vsts I have the inline script that gets the id and key. Do you know how I can save the variables so I can use them in another task (to be specific a shell script task)?

In the inline script I used:
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secretOmsKey;issecret=true]$key"

And in the shell script in the next task I just tried to echo the variable but when use echo "$(secretOmsKey)" it says that it cannot find command secretOmsKey. And when using echo ${secretOmsKey}" it doesn't show anything on the console.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very good at VSTS, maybe you could ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that is very convenient to find Azure Resource IDs is the resource explorer. Navigate your browser to https://resources.azure.com/